# requirejs dependency loaded even condition is false

Tags: requirejs

Why a script tag with the script URL corresponding to require("messages") was injected in HTML file
`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="messages" src="lib/messages.js">    </script>`
even the condition is false ? Thanks.

Here is the code that generates it :

```
 define(function (require) {
        var bool = false;
        if (bool) {
            var messages = require('messages');
            alert(messages.getHello());
        } else{
            alert("Module messages not loaded !");
        }
    });
```

Tested the code below and noticed that the script tag for loading messages.js is not generated

```
define(function (require) {    
    var bool = false;
    if(bool){
        var dep = 'messages'; 
        var messages = require(dep);
        alert(messages.getHello());
   } else{
        alert("Module messages not loaded !!");
   }
});
```

Same here:

```
define(function (require) {
    var bool = false;
    if (bool) {
        var messages = require('messages', function(messages){
            alert(messages.getHello()); 
        });

    } else{
        alert(" Module messages not loaded !");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Require calls without square brackets ( like `require('messages')` ) are parsed from file using regular expressions and treated as dependency of the module it is written in. Author had to take this decision for adding sugar syntax we are talking about here.

If you need to use conditional dependency, you have to use square bracket syntax like below.

```
define(function (require) {
    var bool = false;
    if (bool) {
        require(['messages'], function(messages){ //Note the square brackets around messages
            alert(messages.getHello()); 
        });
    } else{
        alert(" Module messages not loaded !");
    }
});
```

Comment: when and by whom the require calls are parsed ? when you say "Author had to take this decision for adding sugar syntax " to what syntax sugar are you referring to ? thanks

Comment: By author I mean, author of requirejs. By sugar syntax I mean `var messages = require('messages'); `. This should be replaced with `require(['messages'], function(messages){});` which was the earlier syntaxt before sugar syntax was introduced.

Comment: Whenever a file is donwloaded as a dependency by requirejs, it is not executed straight away, requirejs first parses the file for sugar syntax as given in your example.

Comment: this is the code who doesn't generates the script element:

Comment: var bool = false;
    if(bool){
        var dep = 'messages'; 
        var messages = require(dep);
        alert(messages.getHello());
   }

Comment: and here is the code who generates a script tag element:

Comment: if (bool) {
            var messages = require('messages');
            alert(messages.getHello());
        }

Comment: notice that the only difference between the two samples of code is the presence of the variable dep used to store the name of the wanted dependency. how can you explain this behaviour ?

Comment: Regular expression which parses file for require calls expects the require in the quotes. Since the path in not in the quotes when inside variable. Its not picked up as a dependency.

Comment: In your question case 1 and 3 must be calling the require and only in case of 2 its not working. And I dont think it will ever happen even if the bool is true. You can try that.